# Окраска двух разных элементов javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не знал как правильно написать заголовок, так что не ругайтесь. Вообщем проблема такая: Есть 2 элемента с `id` при клике по дочернему элементу я определяю `id` и показываю кнопку при нажатии на которую я крашу кликнутый элемент в красный цвет, но проблема в том, что при клике сначала на один элемент, а потом на второй, и при последнем клики на button у меня в красный окрашивается не последний кликнутый элемент а сразу оба. Думал проблема в том, что нужно подождать время после клика по первому, что бы кнопка пропала, после чего кликнуть по второму => по кнопке и тогда все будет хорошо, но нет. В чем проблема? Вот код:

```
<body>
    <div class="el__1" id="1"><a style="background-color: orange">индикатор</a></div>
    <div class="el__2" id="2"><a style="background-color: orange">индикатор</a></div>

    <button style="display: none">push</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('a').click(function() {
        let id = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        $('button').show();
        setTimeout(() => $('button').hide() , 1500);

        $('button').click(function() {
            $(`.el__${id} > a`).css('background-color', 'red');
            console.log(`.el__${id} > a`);
        }); // end click

    }); // end click

</script>
</body>
```

Вот ссылка на codepen: 
https://codepen.io/Cat_In_Ears/pen/mddPVvm

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  $(".active").toggleClass("red");
});

var timer;
$("a").click(function() {
  $(".orange").removeClass("active");
  $(this).addClass("active");

  $("button").show();
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(() => $("button").hide(), 3000);
});
```

```css
.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el__1" id="1"><a class="orange">индикатор</a></div>
<div class="el__2" id="2"><a class="orange">индикатор</a></div>

<button style="display: none">push</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

В общем проблема была в обработчике событий. Когда я привязываю `button` событие `click`, то оно постоянно привязывается с новым значением `id` при каждом клике по  `a` => Я должен вместе со скрытием кнопки также удалять обработчик событий с button. Вот какой код я написал:

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  let id = $(this).parent('div').attr('id');
  let color = $(`.el__${id} > a`).css('background-color');
  console.log(color)
  $('button').show();

  $('button').click(function() {
    if (color != 'rgb(255, 0, 0)') {
      $(`.el__${id} > a`).css('background-color', 'red');
    } else {
      $(`.el__${id} > a`).css('background-color', 'orange');
    }
  }); // end click

  setTimeout(() => {
    $('button').hide();
    $('button').unbind('click');
  }, 2000);
}); // end click
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="el__1" id="1"><a style="background-color: orange">индикатор</a></div>
<div class="el__2" id="2"><a style="background-color: orange">индикатор</a></div>

<button style="display: none">push</button>
```